# logical and between an image and a const value

Tags: matlab, image-processing, logical-operators

i want write a code for bit plane slicing without using `bitget()`
i want calculate logical and between an image and a const value such as 5 for get bit plane 5
What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `bitand`?

```
fifthBit = bitand( I, 32 ) > 0; % assuming I is an integer type
```